# create file inside directory in bash script

Tags: bash, hdfs

i have a path on HDFS as

```
old_file_path="/user/projects/dir1/dir2/dir3/$variable1/$variable2"
```

where variable1 and variable2 are name of directories stored inside variable.

I want to create a file inside variable2 directory having same name as value stored in variable newMemCount 
command that I am using is

```
hadoop fs -touch $old_file_path/$newMemCount
```

error that I am getting is

```
-touch: Unknown command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hadoop fs` command does not support any `touch` FS shell command, hence your error. It does however support a [`touchz` command](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#touchz) that behaves the same way *nix `touch` would if no file was present (it does however raise an error if a non-empty file exists, while *nix `touch` would just update its modification time).

Therefore, I think you're looking for the following :

```
hadoop fs -touchz $old_file_path/$newMemCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation seems it should be touchz

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#touchz

Comment: thanks..I was able to create using hadoop fs -touchz

Comment: I want to add content to the file created so I am using command hadoop fs -echo $newMemCount > $old_file_path/$newMemCount